# Debug popup window in Firefox

Tags: javascript, debugging, firefox, dom, popup

I'm trying to debug a UI issue that happens only in a popup window (done through window.open) only in Firefox.

What I found is that there is no access to source maps in the popup, even though they are visible in the main window. Because of that you can't pause execution in the popup at all. (I'm trying to pause while a dropdown is open, so I can inspect it).

You can't "Break on... > Subtree Modification" - it simply does nothing.

If you try to `console.log` a piece of DOM in the popup, it fails too. You can't `document.getElementById('myid')` - it only looks through the DOM of the main window, not the popup.

What are my options here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently a legit bug in Firefox: 
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1615355